# Python call function twice, with different args/kwargs, and have it complete different behaviors

Tags: python, function, generator

I have a function object `router_function`.  I want it to have the following behavior:

1. First time calling:

   1. Send `*args` and `**kwargs` to some function `first_call`
   2. Return the return of `first_call`
2. Second time calling:

   1. Send `*args` and `**kwargs` to a second function `second_call`
   2. Return the return of `second_call`

I would prefer for `router_function` not to return a generator object, I just want to be able to directly call it twice.

**How can this be done?**

---

**Sample Code**

I am using Python 3.8.

```py
def first_call(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Call this first."""

def second_call(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Call this second."""

def router_function(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Call the first function, then with this same function object, call the second."""

# Desired behavior
first_call_ret = router_function(1, one=1)  # Calls first_call
second_call_ret = router_function(2, two=2)  # Calls second_call
```

Answer (score 2):

`kwargs` is basically a dictionary and you can take the advantage of it to tell the `router_function` what kind of action you wish to trigger. Let's say if you wanna call the `first_call` function based on an argument, you can pass `1` as a kwargs `call=1` and then retrieve the value of `call` using `kwargs.get("call")` and then conditionally call the associated function which is `first_call` in this case.

Here is an example:

```
def first_call(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Call this first."""
    # you can also access to the params with args array such as args[0]
    return args[0]


def second_call(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Call this second."""
    return 2


def router_function(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Call the first function, then with this same function object, call the second."""
    call = kwargs.get("call")

    if call == 1:
        return first_call(*args, **kwargs)
    elif call == 2:
        return second_call(*args, **kwargs)

    return 0


# Desired behavior
first_call_ret = router_function(100, call=1)  # Calls first_call
second_call_ret = router_function(200, call=2)  # Calls second_call

print(first_call_ret)  # OUTPUT: 100 because we returned the first argument at first_call
print(second_call_ret)  # OUTPUT: 2 since we returned 2 from second_call (hardcoded)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  However, I don't want to have to add another `kwarg` that acts as a switch case, that introduces room for error IMO

Answer (score 0):

The below code sample gets me halfway there. I am really trying to avoid having to bring the generator into the picture, which is where I am stuck.

I want to just call `router_function` directly twice, as I stated in my OP.

```py
from typing import Callable, Iterator

def first_call(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Call this first."""
    return 1

def second_call(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Call this second."""
    return 2

def router_function(*args, **kwargs) -> Iterator[Callable[..., int]]:
    """Call the first function, then with this same function object, call the second."""
    yield from [first_call, second_call]

_gen = router_function()
first_call_ret = next(_gen)(1, one=1)  # 1
second_call_ret = next(_gen)(2, two=1)  # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but here is one way.

In Python, a function is an object and can have attributes just like any other object. Use `getattr()` and `setattr()` to get and set an attribute on the function itself to track if it is the first or second call.

```
def first_call(*args, **kwargs):
    print("first_call")
    
def second_call(*args, **kwargs):
    print("second_call")
    
def router_function(*args, **kwargs):
    if getattr(router_function, "firstcall", True):
        setattr(router_function, "firstcall", False)

        return first_call(*args, **kwargs)

    else:
        return second_call(*args, **kwargs)
```